# Creating duplicate files automatically in a flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, duplicates

I'm new in a flutter. All files are duplicated and a ' 2' (space two) is put in the end of the file's name.

Please check the screen short the BuildConfig duplicate file automatically created.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, please add more details to your question.

Comment: I'd say roll back to your last commit.  You *are* making commits frequently, right?

Comment: yes. I am making commits frequently.